# iPad, UITextView, and firstResponder issues

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

I'm writing a universal iOS app that a text entry component to it. When the view with the UITextView in it is shown, I call [UITextView becomeFirstResponder] so the keyboard pops up. When the user taps done/save, the view controller calls pop on it's navigation controller, and the keyboard *should* disappear automatically.

This works fine on the iPhone/iPod touch, but on the iPad, the keyboard remains up, with the accessory view, even after the view is popped. I've tried everything: checking leaks with Instruments, static analyzer, explicitly calling [UITextView resignFirstResponder] multiple times, heap shots, and no matter what I can't get the keyboard to disappear once the view controller is popped or figure out why the heck it wouldn't be. This is a huge issue because the 'previous' view controller in the UINavigationController hierarchy doesn't have a text field, and the accessory view remains on top of the keyboard and when the buttons on it are tapped, they send messages to the deallocated view controller, causing a crash.

The only difference I can name between the iPhone/iPad version is that the iPhone version, of course, presents the navigation controller modally over the full screen, while on the iPad the navigation controller is presented in UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

I hope this is enough information to allow someone to diagnose the issue. If it's not, I'll post a sample project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the keyboard always shows up while something is presented in UIModalPresentationFormSheet. Try something different and see if that works.

Comment: Good call. That's annoying. Very frustrating too. Any suggestions for showing a modal controller that allows text entry and sane keyboard behavior without using the full screen?

Comment: Not that I know of, though there's probably ways to go about it. Have you tried seeing if a popover will work for you?